# Shelosha Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Shabbat Shalom, everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

בראשית: יז. ה.
ולא יקרא עוד את שמך **אברם** והיה שמך אברהם כי אב המון גוים נתתיך

אברם = 243

[Why was the letter "Hai" added to Avraham's name?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/why-was-the-letter-hai-added-to-avrahams-name)

Answer (score 4):

In a non-leap year, *Shavuot*  is the 243rd day in the year if *Heshvan* and *Kislev* are both Mele'im (have 30 days):

*Tishrei*, *Heshvan*, *Kislev* - 30 days each
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 29 days
*Sivan* - 6 days (*Shavuot* is on the 6th day of *Sivan*)